# Availability group configuration problems - listener not created, error 19407 appears

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

To start with a description of an environment in which the problems are happening:

- 2 SQL servers 2022 Standard in their /28 subnet
- 1 AD domain for several sites, the SQL servers are members of this domain
- Sites and subnets in AD configured so domain knows which IP subnets belong to which sites
- DCs for site with the problems are in different subnet, I don't see any traffic on firewall dropped for DNS, LDAP, etc. between the SQL servers and DCs, though.
- SQL servers are trying to contact DCs from multiple other sites, there I am not sure about exact FW rules (if some portion of the AD related traffic does not get dropped in remote site) and not sure about why they would contact foreign (different site) DCs.
- the listener objects are pre-staged in AD and cluster object has full control over those listener objects

When trying to configure basic AoAG on SQL server, I follow the wizard as 1000x before. The wizard gets stuck at listener creation where it also fails after several minutes. Then it errors out.

When validating cluster, this is given as "validation test fail" (it reports for both nodes):
Connectivity to a writable domain controller from node NodeA.enterprise.int could not be determined because of this error: Could not get domain controller name from machine NodeA.

The error I am getting from SQL server is precisely described here: [Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-19407-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16), however none of those conditions seem true for our case.

Any hint towards fix will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been found out after even more hours and thorough network scrutiny, firewall is to blame (site has recently migrated to L7 firewall). Once FW ruleset has been reconfigured to a way less stringent ruleset, communication works well. It's the network's team turn to fine-tune FW rules in order to avoid this headache from popping up again. Question closed.